# Presenting Data uniformly between two different table presentations with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello Everyone I have a problem…
Table 1 (sorted) is laid out like this:

```
User ID    Producer ID  Company Number
JWROSE     23401        234
KXPEAR     23903        239
LMWEEM     27902        279
KJMORS     18301        183
```

Table 2 (unsorted) looks like this:

```
Client Name       City           Company Number
Rajat Smith       London         JWROSE
Robert Singh      Cleveland      KXPEAR
Alberto Johnson   New York City  LMWEEM
Betty Lee         Dallas         KJMORS
Chase Galvez      Houston        23401
Hassan Jackson    Seattle        23903
Tooti Fruity      Boise          27902
Joe Trump         Tokyo          18301
Donald Biden      Cairo          234
Mike Harris       Rome           239
Kamala Pence      Moscow         279
Adolf Washington  Bangkok        183
```

Now… Table 1 has all of the User IDs and Producer IDs properly rowed with the Company Number.
I want to pull all the data and correctly sorted….

```
Client Name           City           User ID    Producer ID   Company Number
Rajat Smith           London         JWROSE     23401         234
Robert Singh          Cleveland      KXPEAR     23903         239
Alberto Johnson       New York City  LMWEEM     27902         279
Betty Lee             Dallas         KJMORS     18301         183
Chase Galvez          Houston        JWROSE     23401         234
Hassan Jackson        Seattle        KXPEAR     23903         239
Tooti Fruity          Boise          LMWEEM     27902         279
Joe Trump             Tokyo          KJMORS     18301         183
Donald Biden          Cairo          JWROSE     23401         234
Mike Harris           Rome           KXPEAR     23903         239
Kamala Pence          Moscow         LMWEEM     27902         279
Adolf Washington      Bangkok        KJMORS     18301         183
```

Query:

```
Select
b.client_name,
b.city.,
a.user_id,
a.producer_id,
a.company_number

From Table 1 A
Left Join Table 2 B On a.company….
```

And this is where I don’t know what do to….because both tables have all the same variables, but Company Number in Table 2 is mixed with User IDs and Producer IDs... however we know what company Number those ID's are associated to.

Comment: ` is mixed with User IDs and Producer IDs` that's a major bug that needs to be fixed. That data can't be queried by user, product or company ID except by accident. If there's any chance that the same value can be used for two or more types (user, product, company ID) you have **no** way of knowing what you're reading

Comment: The fact that `UserID` is clearly a `varchar`, while the other 2 columns are an `int` really does not make this any better. The problem is the design; you *need* to fix that.

Comment: You might be able to use an OR operator in the join condition.
`From Table 1 A Left Join Table 2 B on a.company number = b.company number OR a.user id = b.company number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mention in the comments, and others do, the real problem is your design. *"The fact that `UserID` is clearly a `varchar`, while the other 2 columns are an `int` really does not make this any better"*, and makes this not simple (and certainly not SARGable).

To get the data in the correct order, as well, you need a column to order it on which the data lacks. I have therefore added a pseudo column, `MissingIDColumn`, to represent this missing column you need to add to your data; which you can do when you fix the design:

```sql
SELECT T2.ClientName,
       T2.City,
       T1.UserID,
       T1.ProducerID,
       T1.CompanyNumber
FROM (VALUES('JWROSE',23401,234),
            ('KXPEAR',23903,239),
            ('LMWEEM',27902,279),
            ('KJMORS',18301,183))T1(UserID,ProducerID,CompanyNumber)
     JOIN (VALUES(1,'Rajat Smith     ','London       ','JWROSE'),
                 (2,'Robert Singh    ','Cleveland    ','KXPEAR'),
                 (3,'Alberto Johnson ','New York City','LMWEEM'),
                 (4,'Betty Lee       ','Dallas       ','KJMORS'),
                 (5,'Chase Galvez    ','Houston      ','23401'),
                 (6,'Hassan Jackson  ','Seattle      ','23903'),
                 (7,'Tooti Fruity    ','Boise        ','27902'),
                 (8,'Joe Trump       ','Tokyo        ','18301'),
                 (9,'Donald Biden    ','Cairo        ','234'),
                 (10,'Mike Harris     ','Rome         ','239'),
                 (11,'Kamala Pence    ','Moscow       ','279'),
                 (12,'Adolf Washington','Bangkok      ','183'))T2(MissingIDColumn,ClientName,City,CompanyNumber) ON T2.CompanyNumber IN (T1.UserID,CONVERT(varchar(6),T1.ProducerID),CONVERT(varchar(6),T1.CompanyNumber))
ORDER BY MissingIDColumn;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do this, but is there anyway to clean up the data without listing the actual values individually? Because the actual data i'm using vs this dummy data example has some 1000 rows...

Comment: @Mo-L you would replace the table value constructs with your tables... I.e. `FROM dbo.Table1 T1`